# Enumerate Microsoft Office products, installed by click-to-run

Tags: winapi, windows-installer, ms-office

I need to get the full list of Office applications, installed on PC. For msi versions, I use MsiEnumProducts(), but it doesn't work with click-to-run versions. The numbering scheme https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2786054 could not be applied here, because there is no records in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall / HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall about Office products, installed by click-to-run. The only records, that points, that click-to-run Office products are installed, are:

- Office 15 Click-to-Run Extensibility Component - {90150000-008C-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE};
- Office 15 Click-to-Run Localization Component - {90150000-008C-0407-1000-0000000FF1CE};
- Office 15 Click-to-Run    Licensing Component - {90150000-007E-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE};

But their product GUIDs could not be used to check separate products, like Word, Excel or PowerPoint, using MsiQueryFeatureState(guid, feature) - returns INSTALLSTATE_UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to look for this apps in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRunStore\Applications

Answer (score 1):

Another way (Office 2019) is you go:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE >> SOFTWARE >> Microsoft >> Windows >> CurrentVersion >> Uninstall >> ProPlus2019Volume
```

[image: Office2019-ProfessionalPlus]